# CSS Menu disappears on hover

Tags: html, css

On the webpage I have a submenu. On hover of "biler til salg" a submenu appears, however, if you try to click the submenu (go away from the parent) the submenu disappears, as you do not hover it anymore.

This is my CSS:

```
.primary-navigation li {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 18px; /* SOLUTION WAS TO REMOVE THIS */
    line-height: 29px;
    position: relative;
}
.primary-navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.primary-navigation ul ul {
    background-color: #dc002e;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.primary-navigation li li {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.0909090909;
}

.primary-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.primary-navigation ul ul a {
    padding: 18px 12px;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 176px;
}

.primary-navigation li:hover > a,
.primary-navigation li.focus > a {
    color: #8f404d;
}

.primary-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.primary-navigation ul ul li.focus > a {
    background-color: #dc002e;
}

.primary-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.primary-navigation ul li:focus > ul {
    left: auto!important;
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the height of the parent li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub menu is hiding because there is a gap between the menu item and sub menu item. The gap is because you are fixing the height of the `li` element to `height: 18px;`. Just remove that height to make it work properly.

I found that height in this part of class:

```
media="all" 
@media screen and (min-width: 783px)
```